# Null Exception Error with Substring

Tags: c#, substring, nullreferenceexception

I am receiving a Null Reference exception error, and it has something to do with either the substring function or the LastIndex function. I am pretty confused why

```
          String[] m_SessionNames;
          String[] filenames; //Filenames already initialized in code
          int Index = 0;
                foreach (String name in filenames)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(filenames[index]) //Works, Displays a string that includes a '\'
                    m_SessionNames[Index] = filenames[Index].Substring((filenames[Index].LastIndexOf('\\') > 0) ? filenames[Index].LastIndexOf('\\') + 1 : 0);
                    Index++;                                                                                                                                                        
                }
```

Comment: Either way, it boils down to `filenames[Index]` being null. Either check for null if it's allowed to be, or fix the code which assigns it if it's not.

Comment: m_SessionNames is not initialized

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry m_SessionsName is initialized. I just forgot to add it to this snippet. I checked for filenames[Index] being null. It is not

Comment: break apart your code and figure out which actual line is throwing the exception.

Comment: String m_SessionNames[]; not like this....like this String[] m_SessionNames;

Comment: ^^ I have it declared like that. I just copied it wrong down during the question. My bad

Comment: Not sure why you are using a foreach then completely ignoring the iterated value?

Comment: Charleh, I've tried replacing filename[index] with name. Doesn't change the output

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get the file name out of a path.

Luckily there is already a method: [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

```
var m_SessionNames = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < filenames.Length; i++)
{
    var filename = filenames[i];

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("filename is null");
        continue;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(filename);

    m_SessionNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(filename));
}

return m_SessionNames.ToArray();
```

Here is a more concise way using Linq.

```
// Get all valid filenames
var sessionNames = filenames.Select(Path.GetFileName)
                            .Where(f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f));

m_SessionNames = sessionNames.ToArray();
```

Comment: That is what I am accomplishing. I will try this and let you know how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately I still receive the error, but I can print out filename, and I do not get the filename is null message.

Comment: The Linq way doesn't produce any Null Exceptions. But I'd like it in a string array if that's possible?

Comment: You need to make sure the `m_SessionNames` array is initialized and it has enough capacity to hold all the file names.

Comment: I have it declared as public String[] m_SessionNames; Thats probably the problem right? I'm not too positive on csharp memory allocation.

Comment: You must initialize the array using the `new` operator. e.g. `string[] m_SessionNames; m_SessionNames = new string[<length>];` You can use a [`List(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) for variable length data.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying  m_SessionNames  and filenames are all already initialized.

If that's the case You should  Not have

String[] m_SessionNames;
String[] filenames;

On top of your code.

Where they are initialized? Even though they may be intialized somewhere else you are declaring 2 new arrays here which are not initialized.

If you are using this code inside a function then declare  m_SessionNames  and file names  in the class level and then populate them. Then in this function you don't need to declare them again.

Comment: The code wouldn't compile if they were in fact not initialized. He wouldn't be able to get the null reference, cause it wouldn't build due to "use of unassigned local...". They definitely need to update their code to something that actually compiles though.

Comment: I have them declared as public members of the class. Do I have to populate them through the constructor?

Comment: Yes you need to initialize them.

Comment: where did you assing and with what can you show the code? if you have not populate them already yes you need to somewhere before you reach this code(i mean initialize them and populate).

Comment: If they are public members(fields) of the class, then you need to initialize them "Every" time you create he class.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be `filenames[Index]`is null. therefore if you invoke any method on the `filenames[Index]` it may produce the NullPointerException. iif the filenames  are already initialized in the code then the reason can be the `m_SessionNames[Index]` and it can be evaluated to null. this is because we cannot see m_SessionNames is not initialized anywhere in the code

Comment: I checked if it was Null. It was not..

Comment: if (filenames[Index] != null)
     MessageBox.Show("hello"); //displayed hello